# Safari on my iPhone 6 is ignoring overflow-x: hidden

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

my site [www.nimaiwalsh.com](http://www.nimaiwalsh.com) appears fine in all browsers and at different sizes except for Mobile Safari on my iPhone 6. A thin white line appears on the right hand side. I have tried everything, and I have had a look at some of the other suggestions regarding overlow-x: hidden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Picture of site on iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bttPW.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Nimai Walsh">
        <meta name="description" content="Web Designer and Developer based in Sydney, Australia. Specialising in responsive and pageless designed sites and offering freelance servives for a number of projects.">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        
        <title>Nimai Walsh - Web Designer and Developer</title>
        
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <header>
            
            <nav>
            
                <div class="row">

                    <img src="resources/img/NW-logo.svg" alt="Nimai Walsh Logo" class="logo">                    
                    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    <a class="mobile-nav-btn js--mobile-nav"><i class="ion-navicon-round"> </i></a>

                </div> 
            
            </nav>
            
            <div class="heading-text-box">
                <h1>Web Designer/Front-End Developer</h1>
                <p class="long-copy">Hi, I'm Nimai Walsh. A web designer and developer currenly based in Sydney, Australia. I specialise in responsive and simple pageless designed sites.</p>
            </div>          
             
        </header> 
        
        <section class="section-portfolio js--section-features" id="portfolio">
            
            <div class="row">
                
                <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                
                    <div class="project-box js--wp-1">
                        
                        <div>
                        
                            <img src="resources/img/omnifood-project.jpg" alt="Omnifood web project">
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="project-details">
                            
                            <ul> 
                                <li><i class="ion-monitor"></i>Web</li>
                                <li><i class="ion-code-working"></i>HTML5, CS3, jQuery</li>
                                <li><i class="ion-compose"></i>A fictional site created as a project to develop my skills</li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                        
                            <a href="projects/omnifood/index.html" target="_blank" class="btn btn-full">Visit site</a>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                
                    <div class="project-box js--wp-2">
                        
                        <div>
                            
                            <img src="resources/img/blog-project.jpg" alt="Nims Playhouse blog project">
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="project-details">
                            
                            <ul> 
                                <li><i class="ion-monitor"></i>Web</li>
                                <li><i class="ion-code-working"></i>Wordpress CMS</li>
                                <li><i class="ion-compose"></i>A personal blog created to explore joyful things in life</li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                        
                            <a href="http://www.nimsplayhouse.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-full">Visit site</a>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                
                      <div class="project-box js--wp-3">
                        
                        <div>
                            
                            <img src="" alt="">
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="project-details">
                            
                            <ul> 
                                <li><i class="ion-monitor"></i></li>
                                <li><i class="ion-code-working"></i></li>
                                <li><i class="ion-compose"></i>A space for my next project. Could it be your site?</li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                        
                            <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-full">Visit site</a>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                
                </div>
            
            </div>
         
        </section>
        
        <section class="section-about" id="about">
            
            <div class="row">
                
                <h2>About me</h2>
            
            </div>
                    
            <div class="row">
                   
                <img id="profile-pic" src="resources/img/profile-pic.jpg" alt="Picture of Nimai Walsh" class="js--wp-4">
                
            </div>
            
              <div class="row">
                  
                  <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                      
                      <p>I completed a Bachelor of Multimedia in 2007, worked as a Web Publisher, a Senior Support Analyst and joined the Royal Australian Navy in 2010. I am completing my service with the Navy at the end of this year to persue my deferred career as a Web Designer and Developer.</p>
                    
                      <p>During the past 6 months I have completed a number of online courses in my own time to develop my skills.</p>
                      
                      <p>I am currently based in Sydney, Australia, but planning to re-locate to Brisbane in 2017.</p>
                      
                      <div id="skills" class="clearfix">
                          
                        <h3>Skills</h3>
                            
                          <ul>
                              
                            <li><i class="ion-social-html5-outline"></i> HTML5</li>
                            <li><i class="ion-social-css3-outline"></i> CSS3</li>  
                            <li>jQuery</li>

                          </ul>
                         
                      
                      </div>
                            
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="col span-1-of-3 twitter-feed">
                          
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/nimaiwalsh" target="_blank"><i id="twitter-icon" class="ion-social-twitter-outline js--twitter-icon"></i></a>
                      
                        <div id="tweecool" class="twitter-widget js--twitter-widget"></div>
                  
                  </div>         
                      
            </div>
                  
        </section>
        
        <section class="section-contact" id="contact">
            
            <div class="row">
            
                <h2>I look forward to hearing from you</h2>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
            
                <ul class="contact-social js--wp-5">
                    <li class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/nimaiwalsh" target="_blank"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="linkedin"><a href="https://au.linkedin.com/in/nimaiwalsh" target="_blank"><i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
                
                <p>+61403676341</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:nimai@nimaiwalsh.com">nimai@nimaiwalsh.com</a></p> 
                
            </div>
            
            <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form js--wp-6">
                
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">

                        <label for="name">Name</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">

                        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">

                        <label for="email">Email</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">

                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>

                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">

                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">

                        <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                
                  <div class="col span-1-of-3">

                        <label for="message">Message</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">

                        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>

                    </div>
                
                </div> 
                
                <div class="row">
                
                  <div class="col span-1-of-3">

                        <label>&nbsp;</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">

                        <input type="submit" value="Hit me up">

                    </div>
                
                </div> 
                
            </form>
            
        </section>
        
        <footer>
            
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                  
                    <ul class="footer-nav">
                        <a href="#portfolio"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
                        <a href="#about"><li>About</li></a>
                        <a href="#contact"><li>Contact</li></a>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="col span-1-of-2"> 
                    
                    <ul class="social-links">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/nimaiwalsh" target="_blank"><li><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></li></a>
                        <a href="https://au.linkedin.com/in/nimaiwalsh"><li><i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i></li></a>
                    </ul>
                
                </div>  
       
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                
                <p>Copyright &copy 2016 Nimai Walsh</p>
                
            </div>        
        
        </footer>
        
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
    <!-- Waypoints jQuery plugin -->
    <script src="vendors/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>    
    
    <!-- Enables old browsers to understand and execute CSS media queries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Enables old browsers to use and style HTML 5 scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Allows use of CSS3 pseudo-classes in IE 6, 7 and 8-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/selectivizr/1.0.3b/selectivizr.min.js"></script>
        
    <!-- jQuery twitter feed -->
    <script src="vendors/js/tweecool.js"></script>    
    
    <script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
        
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
        
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-77429553-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>    
        
    </body>

</html>
```

```css
/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- BASIC SETUP and GLOBAL SETTINGS -- */
/*=======================================*/
* {
    
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

html, body {
    
    color: #707478;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}

.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:after  {
    
    content: ' ';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden; 
}

/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- RE-USABLE COMPONENTS -- */
/*=======================================*/

.row {
    
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

section { padding: 70px 0; }

/* Links */

a:link,
a:visited {
    
    color: #f90;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
    transition: color 0.2s;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
.twitter-feed a i:hover,
.twitter-feed a i:active {
    
    color: #dd8500;
}

/* Headings */

h1, h2, h3 {
    
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 220%;
    color: #fff;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 { 

    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    
} 

h2:after {
    
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #f90;
    content: " ";
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

h3 {
    
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* Paragraph */

.long-copy {
    
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 145%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: #FFAD33;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn:link,
.btn:visited,
input[type=submit] {
    
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
    transition: border 0.2s, background-color 0.2s; 
    
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited,
input[type=submit]{
    
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-color: #f90;
   
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active,
input[type=submit]:hover, 
input[type=submit]:active {
    
    border: 2px solid #DD8500;
    background-color: #DD8500;
}


/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- HEADER SECTION -- */
/*=======================================*/

header {
    
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(9, 112, 84, 0.78)), url(img/header-min.jpg);
    
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(9, 112, 84, 0.78)), url(img/header-min.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

.heading-text-box {
    
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    
}

.logo { 
    
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
}

/* Main nav */
.main-nav {
    
    float:right;
    margin-top: 50px;
    list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li {
    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
    
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF9900;
}

/* Sticky nav */

.sticky {
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #837c7c;
    z-index: 99;
    
}

.sticky .logo {
    
    height: 45px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.sticky .main-nav { margin-top: 15px; }

.sticky .main-nav li a:link,
.sticky .main-nav li a:visited {
    
    color: #707478;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    
}

.sticky .mobile-nav-btn {
    
    margin-top: 8px;
}

/* Mobile nav */

.mobile-nav-btn {
    
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    
}

.mobile-nav-btn i {
    
     font-size: 180%;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- PORTFOLIO SECTION -- */
/*=======================================*/

.project-box {
    
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color:  #707478;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #837c7c; 
}

.project-box div ul {
    
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    line-height: 145%;
}

.project-box div li i {
    
    font-size: 123%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: #dd8500;
    
}

.project-box div img {
    
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #097054;
   
}

.project-box div:last-child {
    
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- ABOUT SECTION -- */
/*=======================================*/

.section-about {
    
    background-color: #097054;
    color: #e2e2e2;
}

#profile-pic {
    
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 40px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.section-about p {
    
    line-height: 145%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#skills h3 {
    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left
}

#skills li {
    
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 0 0 40px; 
}


.twitter-feed i {
    
    font-size: 250%;    
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50%;
    top: -63px;
}

.twitter-widget {
    
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    top: -55px;
}

.twitter-widget li {
    
    list-style: none;
    clear: both;

}

.twitter-widget li .tweets_txt {
    
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.twitter-widget li .tweets_txt span {
    
    font-style: italic;
    color: #ada7a7;
    display: block;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- CONTACT SECTION -- */
/*=======================================*/

.contact-social {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.section-contact p {
    
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 145%;
}

.contact-social li {
    
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.contact-social li.twitter a:hover,
.contact-social li.twitter a:active {
    
    color: #55acee;
}

.contact-social li.linkedin a:hover,
.contact-social li.linkedin a:active {
    
    color: #007bb5;
}

.contact-form {
    
    width: 60%;
    margin: 60px auto;    
}

.contact-form input[type=number],
.contact-form input[type=text],
.contact-form input[type=email],
.contact-form textarea {
    
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dd8500;
}

.contact-form textarea {
    
    height: 100px;
}

*:focus { outline-color: #097054;}

/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- FOOTER SECTION -- */
/*=======================================*/

footer {
    
    background-color: #3c3f43;
    padding: 30px;
}

.footer-nav {
    
    float: left;
    font-size: 80%;    
}

.footer-nav li {
    
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.social-links {
    
    float: right;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.social-links li {
    
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

footer p {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80%;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/
/* -- ANIMATIONS -- */
/*=======================================*/

.js--wp-1, 
.js--wp-2, 
.js--wp-3, 
.js--wp-4,
.js--wp-6 {
    
    opacity: 0;
}

.js--wp-1.animated, 
.js--wp-2.animated, 
.js--wp-3.animated, 
.js--wp-4.animated, 
.js--wp-6.animated {
    
    opacity: 1;
}

.js--wp-5 {
    
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```css
/* Big tablet to 1200px (widths smaller then our 1140px row */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    
    .row { padding: 0 2%; }
    
    .heading-text-box {
    
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 2%;
    
    }   
}

/* Small tablet to big tablet e.g ipad on landscape view: 768px to 1023px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    
    html,
    body {
        
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .twitter-widget {
    
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 10%;
    
    }
    
    .contact-form {
        
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    
}
    
/* Small phones to small tablets: 481px to 767px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    
    html, body {
        
        font-size: 16px;
        
    }
    
    .col {
        
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 4% 0;
    }
    
    .contact-form {
        
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .twitter-widget {
    
        top: 0;
        
    }
    
    .twitter-feed i {
    
        top: 0;    
    
    }
    
    .heading-text-box { margin: 0 4%; } 
    
    /* Use mobile navigation */
    
    .main-nav { display: none; }
    
    .main-nav.show-Nav { display: block; }
    
    .mobile-nav-btn {
        
        display: block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    
    .main-nav {
    
        float:left;
        margin-top: 40px;

    }

    .main-nav li {

        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited { border: 0; }

    .main-nav li a:hover,
    .main-nav li a:active { border: 0; }
    
    .contact-form { width: 80%; }
    
}
    
/* Small phones: 0 to 480px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    .contact-form { width: 100%; }
    
    section { padding: 50px 0;}
    
    .logo { height: 50px; }
    
    .sticky .logo { height: 30px;}
    
    .mobile-nav-btn { margin-top: 25px; }
    .sticky .mobile-nav-btn { margin-top: 2px; }
    
}
```

Comment: You should include a screen capture from Safari on iPhone 6, as well as the relevant CSS/HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the hyphen in "FRONT-END" and the left margin applied to `.heading-text-box`. To take people's eye off of the hyphen on small screens, I would try something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .heading-text-box {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  h1 {
    letter-spacing: normal;
  }
}
```

It will look something like this after these two tweaks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy, you are a Genius.